Adding new value to current style of an element
I have an element that currently has the following styles:

max-height: 100px
min-width: 200px

These values are constantly dependent on the device or viewport the user has. I want to add the value display: none to that element and not remove the current max-height and min-width.
cy.get('#my-element').invoke('addClass', 'style', 'display: none')

The above code seems not to work. The output I am expecting should be:

max-height: 100px
min-width: 200px
display: none

What can I do as a workaround for this?

The simplest way is to invoke hide.
With this simple div
<div style="max-height: 150px; min-width: 200px;">Hide me</div>

and this test
cy.get('div')
  .should('have.css', 'max-height', '150px')
  .and('have.css', 'min-width', '200px')

cy.get('div').invoke('hide')

cy.get('div')
  .should('have.css', 'display', 'none')
  .and('have.css', 'max-height', '150px')
  .and('have.css', 'min-width', '200px')
  .and('not.be.visible')

this is the test result

